How can I make the text in the red div actually be in the div so when its expanded it'll display all the text?
I've been trying to make an interesting function where if you hover your cursor over the red div/ the red box it'll make it expand and reveal some more text with the use of a vertical linear transition. However, I can't seem to figure out how to make it happen.
I don't know how to phrase it to find results to help me with my issue so I came on here to get some help.
And here's the code for that div.


.box {
  transform: translatey(-20px);
  background: #9b59b6;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.key {
  height: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 2s, height 2s;
}

.key:hover {
  height: 500px;
}
<div class="box key">
  <h1 ID="super">Trying to put it here</h1>
</div>




I can’t see any more text, where is it?

Like... this? I tried and it worked. You can edit for your taste although.
 <div class="box key">
    <h1 id="super">Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
    </h1>
  </div>

Also you could edit your :hover's height from text id's (super) height this way so no need to redefine it all the time.
html
<div class="box key">
    <h1 id="super">Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
        Trying to put it here
    </h1>
  </div>

js
<script>
    const elementsuper = document.getElementById('super');
    const elementsuperHeight = elementsuper.clientHeight;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--superHeight', `${elementsuperHeight}px`);
  </script>

css
.key:hover {
  height: var(--superHeight);
}



        


thank you for taking the time to answer my post. For some reason the css code isn’t working. Would it be because the css code you provided was internal? I’m using a separate css file to style my html file. I only put the styling on the same thing for the post I made because I’m new to this platform. It does work perfectly on its own though.

adding style from external css file is not unusual and it is still possible adding this hover style your own css file. you only add 